# Replace str1 with str2 and vice versa

Tags: php

Suppose I have a text like the following

> John is John and Sara is Sara

I want to turn it to:

> Sara is Sara and John is John

If I execute `str_replace("John", "Sara", $input)`, then there will be no more *John* and `str_replace("Sara", "John", $input)` would turn all names to *John*. So how can I do this?

Is there a built-in function to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an array in order to not run multiple replacements, however `str_replace` will not yield the correct results.  Given *`John is John and Sara is Sara`*:

```
$result = str_replace(['John', 'Sara'], ['Sara', 'John'], $string);
```

Yields: *`John is John and John is John`*

You need to use `strtr` because of the way it searches, and replaces eliminate this issue:

```
$result = strtr($string, ['John'=>'Sara', 'Sara'=>'John']);
```

Yields: *`Sara is Sara and John is John`*

From the manual [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

> The longest keys will be tried first. **Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again**.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a built in per se but you can split the chunks into an array, reverse them, and then rejoin:

```
$new = implode(' and ', array_reverse(explode(' and ', $input)));
```

This assumes that your input matches the format `<whatever> and <whatever>`.